# Excel Date error importing with Python Pandas - 'must be string, not Timestamp'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I am trying to plot my Excel time series data. Would appreciate any help possible. Using syntax from various forums allowed me to plot the time series Excel data, but only if the Date was using a `2014.1.1` as opposed to `2014/1/1`, and in text format.

If I use the proper data, it produces this error:
    df.Date = df.Date.apply( lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d').date())
    TypeError: must be string, not Timestamp

The data (for water quality) looks like this:
    Session Date    Location_   Location_code   Faecal_coliforms    E._coli Faecal_streptococcus
    1   12-Jun-13   Mhlanga-Main_Beach  5   4   1   8   0.78    8.19
    1   12-Jun-13   Mhlanga-Bronze_Beach    4   2   1   4   0.67    8.16
    1   12-Jun-13   Mdloti-Main_Beach   3   1   1   1   0.78    8.14
    1   12-Jun-13   Mdloti-Tidal_Pool   2   1   1   1   0.67    8.18
    2   20-Jun-13   uMgababa_Beach  13  1   1   4   1.64    8.16

The script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

path2file = r"BF_data3a.xlsx"
_xl = pd.ExcelFile(path2file)
df = pd.read_excel(path2file, _xl.sheet_names[0], header=0) 

df.Date = df.Date.apply( lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%m/%d').date())
df.index = df.Date 
del df['Date']
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that the `Date` field is already a `Timestamp`, so can't be converted using `strptime`. What if you remove that step entirely?

Comment: Thanks for that, seems like a step in the right direction.Interesting, it plots and image, but now has a new error that never happened with the ammended data, plus the data is a little all over:plt.plot_date(g['E._coli'].index, g['E._coli'], linestyle='None', marker='o', mfc=colors[i], label=k)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please reduce your code to the _minimum_ needed to show your problem and don't change questions half way through.  People are happy to help you understand how to use the libraries, but are less happy to do drop-at-a-time debugging for you.

Comment: Thanks tcaswell for the input. I have reduce the code as suggested. For those who have a simliar issue, by placing a # infront of the df.Date = df.Date.apply..as suggested by jonrsharpe, the script works, although it appears to introduce other errors not happening, when the script includes the blocked code, but has the 2014.01.01 type format. Hope this helps others. Thanks to all for the assistance.